# Search for existence of a file with partial file name in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to find whether a file with partial name (not full name but something like filename%.txt) is available in a directory.

How to use wildcard characters (% and _) for searching availability of a file?

Can we use wildcard characters in FILEEXIST function in sas?

Comment: No, wildcards in the path will make the FILEEXIST function return 0

Answer (score 2):

```
filename search pipe "dir /B c:\temp\bet*.txt";
data _Null_;
  infile search;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Does this solution work for Unix and Windows, or is it specific to just one environment? Do you need admin privileges to run PIPE commands?

Comment: Yes, it will work for UNIX, but you need, of course, to change to the ls command. In order to use pipe filename device through a SAS session started through an objectspawner (as you do in EG) the workspaceserver need to have the ALLOWXCMD option set by the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This code will return the filenames, but it will read the entire file, so probably not a good idea if they are large:

```
filename search "c:\temp\bet*.txt";
data _Null_;
  attrib filevar length=$1024;
  retain filevar "";
  infile search filename=filevar;
  input;
  if filevar ne lag(filevar) then put filevar;
run;
```

I tried to use firstobs and obs to only read one line from each file, but didn't succeed.

If you are happy with getting only the first filename that matches, this code should do it:

```
filename search "c:\temp\bet*.txt";
data _Null_;
  attrib filevar length=$1024;
  infile search filename=filevar;
  put filevar;
run;
```

If you don't get a match, you will get this error:

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, c:\temp\bet*.txt.
```

Answer (score 1):

Stig Eide's method is simple and effective.
An alternative approach to work with directories and files in SAS is using the functions dopen, dnum, dread and dclose.
Here's an example to scan all the files in a directory:

```
%let dir= your_path;
data _null_;
    rc=filename("filrf","&dir.");
    did=dopen("filrf");
    nfile=dnum(did);
    do j = 1 to nfile;
        filename= dread(did,j);
        str= 'File n. '||strip(j)||' has name: '||filename;
        put str;
    end;
    rc=dclose(did);
run;
```

To investigate the existence of a particular file you just need to add some kind of check, as with Stig's example.
You can also handle this in macro language using the same functions.

Here's an example that includes a check on the filename:

```
%macro search(dir=,str=); 
    %global file_exists; 
    /* Assigns a fileref to the directory and opens the directory */                                                                    
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir.));                                                                                                
    %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf.));                                                                                                      
    /* Returns the number of members in the directory */                                                                   
    %let nfile=%sysfunc(dnum(&did.));                                                                                                  
    /* Loops through entire directory */
    %let file_exists=0;
    %do j = 1 %to &nfile.;
        /* Checks if the j-th member name matches the wildcard */
        %put Analyzing file %qsysfunc(dread(&did.,&j.));
        %if %index(%qupcase(%qsysfunc(dread(&did.,&j.))),%qupcase(&str.)) > 0 
                %then %do;
            %let file_exists=1;
            %put Match found!;
        %end;
    %end;
    %if (&file_exists.=0) %then %put No match found!;
    /* Closes the directory */                                                                                                            
    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did.));                                                                                                        
%mend search; 

%search(dir=path_dir, str=wildcard)
%put file_exists= &file_exists.;
```

The q-version of the %qupcase and %qsysfunc functions is required only to handle special characters like %.

Hope this helps! :)